# Moving an element in a python list if the element is a list itself

Tags: python, list, insert

So, I'm making a code that takes the historical values of the indicated stock prices and returns a list of the Value at risk, it doesn't matter what that is, the problem is the following:

the original list is displayed like this:

```
[['AMZN.csv', 2.289891777445866], ['BTC.csv', 5.453298793696432], ['FB.csv', 2.956361117388685], ['GOLD.csv', 1.2924516171324278], ['GOOG.csv', 2.7525367824881473], ['GSPC.csv', 2.4573561011238243], ['NFLX.csv', 3.155830089346503]]
```

What I want is that the element with the smallest numerical value is the first element (index 0), the second smallest with its element in the index 1 and so on, here is the code I've been trying so far:

```
smallestValue=varList[0][1]
smallestIndex=0
smallestElement=varList[smallestIndex]
for q in range(len(varList)):
    currentSymbol=varList[q][1]
    if currentSymbol <= smallestValue and varList[q] != smallestElement:
        smallestValue=currentSymbol
        smallestIndex=q
        smallestElement=varList[q]
        print(smallestElement)
        varList.pop(smallestIndex)
        varList.insert(0,smallestElement)
        print(varList)
        q-=1
```

It prints the following:

```
['GOLD.csv', 1.2924516171324278]
[['GOLD.csv', 1.2924516171324278], ['AMZN.csv', 2.289891777445866], ['BTC.csv', 5.453298793696432], ['FB.csv', 2.956361117388685], ['GOOG.csv', 2.7525367824881473], ['GSPC.csv', 2.4573561011238243], ['NFLX.csv', 3.155830089346503]]
```

I know the solution is probably something very easy. but my deadline is in a day and as a normal human being I put this off until yesterday and I've coding all night, I'm blocked right now hehe.

Comment: You want sort the list. You `list.sort` or `sorted` with `key` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I didn't misunderstand the problem, the solution is simple indeed:

```
newList = sorted(varList, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my own issue, just in case someone finds this useful in the future:

```
order=False
q=0
while order==False:
    currentElement=varList[q]
    currentValue = varList[q][1]
    if q>0:
        preValue=varList[q-1][1]
        if currentValue<=preValue:
            varList.pop(q)
            varList.insert(q-1,currentElement)
            q=0
    q+=1
    if q==len(varList):
        order=True

print(varList)
```

Finally, the end result:

```
[['GOLD.csv', 1.2924516171324278], ['AMZN.csv', 2.289891777445866], ['GSPC.csv', 2.4573561011238243], ['GOOG.csv', 2.7525367824881473], ['FB.csv', 2.956361117388685], ['NFLX.csv', 3.155830089346503], ['BTC.csv', 5.453298793696432]]
```